# Issue With sigvec When Moving to New GCC/Red Hat Version

Tags: c++

I work on a legacy system with old roots, and we're moving from Red Hat Linux 6 to 8, and GCC 4.4.7 to 8.3.1. I'm currently fixing up compilation problems and have a roadblock.

The problem I've run into is that the "sigvec" struct and function are no longer defined in signal.h on the newer system, and I can't find definitions for them in any other include files. The man pages on the new system indicate that signal.h is where they should be.

It also recommends using the POSIX signal API, but considering the legacy code and my lack of experience in this area of a fairly large product code base, I'd prefer keeping the status quo. This is low-level stuff; I'll dig into it if I have to, but if there's an easy workaround, I'd much prefer that.

Is there a package that we should install, or are these buried somewhere in an include file that I'm just not finding? I've searched Google a bit, but haven't found anything on this.

Comment: We're opening a Red Hat support request also, but I don't know how quickly that will come back.

Answer (score 0):

We received word back from Red Hat Support that sigvec support has been removed recently. Rewriting the code appears to be the only option.